# How to change Joomla broken Jooma link to new one

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm stuck for about 2 hours now and can't solve this issue.

On this [page](http://csvr.org.za/programmes), there are 6 links starting by (Advocacy) and finishing by (Research) located on the Left side of the page.

I need to re-link each of these link to the correct article.

I have all the articles in place, but I'm unable to link them to they respective articles.

I tried to go to "Menu Items" but it doesn't appear to be Menu as I tried to link but have not worked.

Please can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it might be a custom HTML module which can be edited in Extensions -> Modules.

Comment: Thanks so so much !!!  It's solved.   I also want to learn. How did know that it was under Extension / Modules??   Is it because of its "CUSTOM" class when I inspect it in Google Chrome?  or something else?  Please tell me.  Below is that code snippet <div class="custom">
 <p><a href="/index.php/programmes/advocacy.html?layout=default">Advocacy</a></p>...</div>      If so, meaning that everything that has "custom" needs to be modified under Module?   Please can you tell me more.

Comment: The "custom" class was exactly the clue I spotted.